# How can I make $a^{21}+b^{21}+c^{21}$ out of $a+b+c$, $a^2+b^2+c^2$, and $a^3+b^3+c^3$?

Tags: polynomials, symmetric-polynomials

How can I make $a^{21}+b^{21}+c^{21}$ out of $a+b+c$, $a^2+b^2+c^2$, and $a^3+b^3+c^3$? Basically, I'm wondering how to manipulate the three expressions to get exactly $a^{21}+b^{21}+c^{21}$. However, since the exponents are so large, it is difficult to see how to manipulate them. Any help? Thanks!

Comment: see what you can do for $a^4 + b^4 + c^4$ and $a^5 + b^5 + c^5$

Comment: Lookup [Newton's identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities#Formulation_in_terms_of_symmetric_polynomials).

Comment: In this problem, is there a good way to find those values or is it just guessing what to multiply and such?

Comment: Is there a more easier to understand explanation? I'm not good at sum and product notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a+b+c=x$, $a^2+b^2+c^2=y$ and $a^3+b^3+c^3=z$.

Firstly, we can get $ab+ac+bc=\frac{1}{2}(x^2-y)$ and $abc$ from
$$z=x^3-3x\cdot\frac{1}{2}(x^2-y)+3abc.$$

Now, since $a^{21}+b^{21}+c^{21}$ is a symmetric polynomial,

we can write it like polynomial of $a+b+c$, $ab+ac+bc$ and $abc$.

Comment: I know that it's possible, but how do I form it? Thanks!

Comment: @user406996 It's a lot of work! I can show it by hand for $a^4+b^4+c^4$, for $a^5+b^5+c^5$, $a^6+b^6+c^6$ and more. For $a^{21}+b^{21}+c^{21}$ it's smooth, but it's very ugly. By the way, you can use Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: What should I plug into Alpha? This is my first time using it! :)

Comment: Try http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=SymmetricReduction%5Ba%5E21%2Bb%5E21%2Bc%5E21%2C+%7Ba%2Cb%2Cc%7D%2C+%7Bx%2C+%28x%5E2-y%29%2F2%2C%28z-x%5E3%2B3%2F2x%28x%5E2-2y%29%29%2F3%7D%5D&x=6&y=11

Comment: @user406996 see here:  http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=SymmetricReduction%5Bx%5E21%2By%5E21%2Bz%5E21,%7Bx,y,z%7D%5D

Comment: Ok, well that clearly isn't good! If $a+b+c=1, a^2+b^2+c^2=3, $ and $a^3+b^3+c^3=7$, how would I find the value of $a^{21}+b^{21}+c^{21}$?

Comment: @user406996 This thing we can get by hand, of course! Because $a$, $b$ and $c$ are roots of the equation $x^3-x^2-x-1=0$.

Comment: wait, how did you get that polynomial? :o

Comment: @user406996 Because $2(ab+ac+bc)=(a+b+c)^2-a^2-b^2-c^2=1-3=-2$, which gives $ab+ac+bc=-1$. By the same way $abc=1$. From here $a^{21}+b^{21}+c^{21}=361109$.

Comment: ok! I think I kinda get it!

Answer (score 2):

Let $s(n)=a^n+b^n+c^n$. The sequence has a recursion based on the polynomial $$(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)=x^3-e_1x^2+e_2x-e_3$$ where $e_1,e_2,e_3$ are the elementary symmetric functions. The recursion is $$s(n)=e_1s(n-1)-e_2s(n-2)+e_3s(n-3).$$ Using this recursion you can find any $s(n)$ given $s(1),s(2),s(3)$.